# How To fix "add-member : Cannot add a member with the name "" because a member with that name already exists"

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell

I need to list multiple FTP connexion on LogicApp service and export this list on csv file. This export is use for see if the SSL protocol connexion is activate or not. My script generate this error.

*add-member : Cannot add a member with the name "FTP" because a member with that name already exists. To overwrite the member anyway, add the Force parameter to your command.*

LogicApp FTP connexion : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-ftp

I need to add these FTP connections in this format on excel :

[format need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGD6G.png)

```
            $LogicApp_temp = $null
            $LogicApp_obj = @()
            $LogicApp_temp = new-object PSObject

            $FTPAll = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $RG -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/connections

            foreach ( $FTPAlls in $FTPAll ) {

            $FTPName = $FTPAlls.name

            $FTPName1 = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $RG -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/connections -Name $FTPName 

            foreach ($FTPName2 in $FTPName1) {

            $FTPcheckType = $FTPName2.Properties.api.name

            if ( $FTPcheckType -eq  "ftp") {

            $FTPSSL1 = $FTPName1.Properties.parameterValues.isSSL

            }

            else {

            }
                $LogicApp_temp | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FTP" -Value "$FTPName2.Properties.displayName $FTPSSL1"
            }

            }
            $LogicApp_obj += $LogicApp_temp
            Write-Output "LogicApp Name : $Name Ressource Group : $RG OK"

            # CSV Exports : 
            $LogicApp_obj | Export-Csv $csvPath -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I don't see where `$LogicApp_temp` is being created. You will need a new object called `$LogicApp_temp` for each loop iteration for your code to be successful.

Comment: `Add-Member` has a `-Force` switch

Comment: Please include the complete script about the creation of `$LogicApp_temp`.

Comment: Thx for your comment ;) i have edit my script.

Comment: The -force replace the save value on $LogicApp_temp in each passage of the loop. But my goal is to list all FTP connexion in FTP member on my CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `PSObject` property just could be set one value at one time, if you use the `-Force`, it will overwrite the value before.

If you want to get the `.csv` file like the format you provided, we could just append every string like `joyftp True` first.

**My working sample**:

```
$RG = "<resource group name>"  

$LogicApp_obj = @()
$value = ""

$FTPAll = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $RG -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/connections

foreach ( $FTPAlls in $FTPAll ) {

$FTPName = $FTPAlls.name

$FTPName1 = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $RG -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/connections -Name $FTPName 

foreach ($FTPName2 in $FTPName1) {

$FTPcheckType = $FTPName2.Properties.api.name
$displayname = $FTPName2.Properties.displayName
$LogicApp_temp = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

if ( $FTPcheckType -eq  "ftp") {


$FTPSSL1 = $FTPName1.Properties.parameterValues.isSSL

$value += "$displayname $FTPSSL1 | "
$LogicApp_temp | add-member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FTP" -Value "$value" -Force 

}

}

}

Write-Output "LogicApp Name : $Name Ressource Group : $RG OK"

# CSV Exports : 
$LogicApp_temp | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\ftp.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**The `.csv` file**:

[image]